# Using a for loop to dyanmically populate an array from a text Form

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to a) create a dymic form that more entry lines can be added to and then b) use the text in those lines to create a separate text output via a template. I'm running into a snag using a for loop to dynamically populate arrays I'm trying to use to store the information.

Here's the code:

```
function Start_TemplateBuilder(){

var A = [10];

var B = [10];

var Etc = document.getElementById("Etc"); /*There are multiple instance of this created dynamically via javascript from a form, which labels them as Etc1, Etc2, etc. */

var More = document.getElementById("More");  /*There are multiple instance of this created dynamically via javascript from a form, which labels them as More1, More2, etc.  */

A[0] = document.getElementById("Etc");

B[0] = document.getElementById("More");

var text_compile = '';

for (var comparison = 1; comparison < entry_iterative; comparison++){                 

/* entry_iterative is defined as a global variable outside of this function and starts at 1 */

A[comparison] = document.getElementById(Etc + comparison);                       /* Here’s where I’m trying to use a for loop to populate Etc 1 thru 10 and More 1 thru 10 as needed, and trying to reference specific entries in A based on the comparison variable */

B[comparison] = document.getElementById(More + comparison);
}


/* more below, but this is where I’m hitting a wall */
```

It doesn’t seem that the array is being properly populated in the for loop. Is it possible use java script to dynamically fill the array, or will I need to use a host of if statements?

If it helps, here’s the code used to dynamically update the form:

```
function Add_Entry(){

text_0b +=                          "<br><input type = 'text' id = 'Etc" + entry_iterative + "' value = 'Enter the next entry' />";

text_0b +=                          "<br><input type = 'text' id = 'More" + entry_iterative + "' value = 'Enter protoc of the next entry in (X) format' />";

text_0 = text_0a;  /* Global variables defined outside the function */
text_0 += text_0b;
text_0 += text_0c;
output_0.innerHTML = text_0;

entry_iterative++;
}
```

Comment: In A[comparison] = document.getElementById(Etc + comparison) shouldn't Etc be betwen quotes?

Comment: I tried that with no improvements, regretably. It's returning a null value in the test alert I set up.